# Magento 2: filter results by date, ->addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento2

I am using the object manager (directly and intentionally) to get the sales quantity of a product.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = 101;
$sold_products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection')
                             ->addOrderedQty()
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $product_id)
                             ->getFirstItem();
```

This successfully allows me to get the quantity sold of a product by passing in the product ID to the attribute filter. Now I want to filter the results by a starting and end date...

```
$start_date = '2001-12-12 12:12';
$end_date = '2019-12-12 12:12';
```

... by adding this to the object manager parameters:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $start_date,'to' => $end_date))
```

But I can't seem to get this code to work. How do I filter results by a starting and end date?

**EDIT**: Workaround solution -
The accepted answer works perfectly, however I ended up having to use the following workaround, which is a little slower but works perfectly fine too. Posting in case it helps anyone in a similar situation.

```
$salesRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory');
$sold_products = $salesRepository->create()
                                 ->getCollection()
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $product_id);

foreach ($sold_products as $sold_product) {
    $created_at = $sold_product->getData('created_at');
    if ($created_at < $start_date || $created_at > $end_date) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $created_at."<br>";
}
```

This will get you only the products within the specified date range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2001-12-12'));
$endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2019-12-12'));

->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vinz. I believe this is the correct solution, however it is not working for me. I am getting the error: 

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous`

Which means that I am trying to select the `created_at` column from multiple tables and it doesn't know which one to take it from. Do you know how to find which table a Magento function is calling?

Comment: Your solution works, but because of my unique situation and how my DB was setup, I was getting errors. So I'm posting my unique solution in case anybody is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution:

```
$start_date = '2001-12-12 12:12';
$end_date = '2019-12-12 12:12';
$salesRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory');
$sold_products = $salesRepository->create()
                                 ->getCollection()
                                 ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', $product_id);

foreach ($sold_products as $sold_product) {
    $created_at = $sold_product->getData('created_at');
    if ($created_at < $start_date || $created_at > $end_date) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $created_at."<br>";
}
```